# Running into problems with .NET 6 in creating a migration to a SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, migration

I've been trying to deal with doing a migration to a SQL Server database. I'm getting this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'DatacussContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here is my `program.cs` code:

```
using datacuss.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatacussContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Datacuss"));
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Here is the `Context` class:

```
using datacuss.Data.Configurations;
using datacuss.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace datacuss.Data
{
    public class DatacussContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatacussContext(DbContextOptions<DatacussContext> options) : base(options) 
        { 
        }

        public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ApplyConfiguration(new UserGroupConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Configuration` class:

```
using datacuss.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace datacuss.Data.Configurations
{
    public class UserGroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserGroup>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserGroup> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(x => x.State).HasMaxLength(2);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).UseIdentityColumn(100010, 10);
            builder.Property(x => x.StreetAddress).HasColumnName("Street Address");
            builder.Property(x => x.PostalCode).HasColumnName("Zip / Postal Code");
            builder.Property(x => x.ContactName).HasColumnName("Contact Name");
            builder.Property(x => x.ContactPhone).HasColumnName("Contact Phone");
            builder.Property(x => x.InvoiceEmail).HasColumnName("Invoice E-mail");
            builder.Property(x => x.ApplicationID).HasColumnName("Application ID");
            builder.Property(x => x.InvFundAR).HasColumnName("Invoice Fund AR");
            builder.Property(x => x.InvInclExcelFile).HasColumnName("Invoice Include Excel File");

            builder.HasData(new List<UserGroup>
            {
                new UserGroup {
                    Id=100010,
                    Name="Evance Business Services",
                    Status=1,
                    Created=DateTime.Now,
                    StreetAddress="507 Weston Ridge Drive",
                    City="Naperville",
                    State="IL",
                    PostalCode="60563",
                    ContactName="Bill Paulding",
                    ContactPhone="3313333333",
                    InvoiceEmail="bpaulding@evance.com",
                    ApplicationID=1,
                    InvFundAR=0,
                    InvInclExcelFile=0,
                    InvTypeID=1
                },
                new UserGroup {
                    Id=100020,
                    Name="Sample Staffing Company",
                    Status=1,
                    Created=DateTime.Now,
                    StreetAddress="507 Weston Ridge Drive",
                    City="Naperville",
                    State="IL",
                    PostalCode="60563",
                    ContactName="Bill Paulding",
                    ContactPhone="3313333333",
                    InvoiceEmail="bpaulding@evance.com",
                    ApplicationID=1,
                    InvFundAR=0,
                    InvInclExcelFile=0,
                    InvTypeID=1
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My `UserGroup` class

```
namespace datacuss.Models
{
    public class UserGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string? ContactPhone { get; set; }
        public string? ContactFax { get; set; }
        public string? InvoiceEmail { get; set; }
        public int? ApplicationID { get; set; }
        public int InvFundAR { get; set; }
        public int InvInclExcelFile { get; set; }
        public int InvTypeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally the `AppSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Datacuss": "Data Source=DESKTOP-M4T8DMP\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=datacuss;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

Well, I tried doing some minor code adjustments per the link but they don't work.

Comment: Try moving DatacussContext initialization before "var app = builder.Build();" line, you app is built before DatacussContext inject to the builder.

Comment: Well, that DEFINITELY solved it! Thank you!